# What is difference between normal functions and typeclass functions?

Tags: haskell

```hs
class (Typeable e, Show e) => Exception e where
    toException   :: e -> SomeException
    fromException :: SomeException -> Maybe e

    toException = SomeException
    fromException (SomeException e) = cast e
```

```
data MyException1 = Exception1A | Exception1B
    deriving (Show)
instance Exception MyException1

data MyException2 = Exception2A | Exception2B
    deriving (Show)
instance Exception MyException2
```

It is able to define multiple exceptions. So, multiple `fromException` functions are able to be defined too. I think it is weird because two functions can have same name and same input.

```hs
fromException :: SomeException -> Maybe MyException1
fromException :: SomeException -> Maybe MyException2
```

Even if the reason why this behavior is ok is "Two functions have different type include return type (and expressions are  evaluated based these all types)", it is weird, because I can't define normal functions that way.

```hs
f :: Integer -> Maybe Integer
f = cast

f :: Integer -> Maybe Char
f n = cast $ show n
```

What is difference between normal functions and type class functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you cannot define normal functions that way is the whole difference.

The whole purpose of type classes is to allow *overloading* - that is, defining multiple different functions with different types, but same name. And have the compiler pick the right one automatically based on types expected in the context.